# Axis Label 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, labeling, plot-themes

I want to move the two horizontal axes closer to the axes keeping the same writing style (the label parallel to the axis), and also, the vertical axis should be parallel to the vertical label. Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

```
f7[n1_, l1_, m1_, a1_, n2_, l2_, m2_, a2_, q_] := 
 Module[{m = 0, n = n1 - l1 - 1, 
   del = ((a2/a1*n2) + (a1*n1))/(n1*a2*n2), 
   gamma = l1 + l2 + k1 + 3/2, beta = 2/(a1*n1), mu = q, 
   alpha = 2*l1 + 1, nu = l + 1/2},
  N1 = 4*\[Pi]*2/(
    a1^(3/2)*n1^2)*2/((a2/a1)^(3/2)*
     n2^2)*\[Sqrt]((n1 - l1 - 1)!/(n1 + l1)!*(n2 - l2 - 1)!/(n2 + 
          l2)!)*(2/(a1*n1))^l1*(2/(a2/a1*n2))^l2*\[Sqrt](\[Pi]/(2*q))*
    KroneckerDelta[m, 0];
  Il = Sum[(n2 + l2)!*((-1)^k1 2^k1*(-beta)^k*mu^nu*
      Gamma[n + alpha + 1])/(
     k1!*(n2 - l2 - 1 - k1)!*(2*l2 + k1 + 1)!*(a2/a1)^k1*n2^
      k1)*(Gamma[
        nu + gamma + k + 1]/(Gamma[k + 1]*Gamma[n - k + 1]*
         Gamma[alpha + k + 1]*2^nu*Gamma[nu + 1]*
         del^(nu + gamma + k + 1)))*
     Hypergeometric2F1[(nu + gamma + k + 1)/2, (nu + gamma + k + 2)/2,
       1 + nu, -mu^2/del^2], {k, 0, n}, {k1, 0, n2 - l2 - 1}]; 
  Al = I^l*\[Sqrt]((2*l + 1)/(4*\[Pi]))*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 0}, {l2, 0}, {l, 0}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 
      m1}, {l2, -m2}, {l, -m}]*(-1)^(m2 + 
       m)*\[Sqrt](((2*l1 + 1)*(2*l2 + 1)*(2*l + 1))/(4*\[Pi]));
  
  temp1 = Sum[N1*Al*Il, {l, Abs[l1 - l2], l1 + l2}];
  {temp1} // N
  ]

Show[Plot3D[f7[4, 2, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, a, q], {a, 1, 5}, {q, 0, .6}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, Background -> White, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{a, q, z}, White], PlotRange -> Full, 
  ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Black, BoxStyle -> Black, 
  TicksStyle -> Black, AxesStyle -> Black],  
 AxesLabel -> {Rotate["ratio of Bohr radii \[Rho] ", -20 Degree, 
    Black], Rotate["transferred momentum\n q in atomic unit
", 60 Degree], Rotate["form factor ", 90 Degree]}]
```

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f7[n1_, l1_, m1_, a1_, n2_, l2_, m2_, a2_, q_] :=
 Module[
  {m = 0, n = n1 - l1 - 1, del = ((a2/a1*n2) + (a1*n1))/(n1*a2*n2), 
   gamma = l1 + l2 + k1 + 3/2, beta = 2/(a1*n1), mu = q, alpha = 2*l1 + 1, 
   nu = l + 1/2},
  N1 = 4*π*2/(a1^(3/2)*n1^2)*2/((a2/a1)^(3/2)*
       n2^2)*√((n1 - l1 - 1)!/(n1 + l1)!*(n2 - l2 - 1)!/(n2 + 
           l2)!)*(2/(a1*n1))^l1*(2/(a2/a1*n2))^l2*√(π/(2*q))*
    KroneckerDelta[m, 0];
  Il = Sum[(n2 + l2)!*((-1)^k1 2^k1*(-beta)^k*mu^nu*
        Gamma[n + alpha + 
          1])/(k1!*(n2 - l2 - 1 - k1)!*(2*l2 + k1 + 1)!*(a2/a1)^k1*
        n2^k1)*(Gamma[
        nu + gamma + k + 1]/(Gamma[k + 1]*Gamma[n - k + 1]*
         Gamma[alpha + k + 1]*2^nu*Gamma[nu + 1]*del^(nu + gamma + k + 1)))*
     Hypergeometric2F1[(nu + gamma + k + 1)/2, (nu + gamma + k + 2)/2, 
      1 + nu, -mu^2/del^2], {k, 0, n}, {k1, 0, n2 - l2 - 1}];
  Al = I^l*√((2*l + 1)/(4*π))*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 0}, {l2, 0}, {l, 0}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 
      m1}, {l2, -m2}, {l, -m}]*(-1)^(m2 + 
       m)*√(((2*l1 + 1)*(2*l2 + 1)*(2*l + 1))/(4*π));
  temp1 = Sum[N1*Al*Il, {l, Abs[l1 - l2], l1 + l2}] // N]
```

Labels:

```
lbls = {
   Rotate["ratio of Bohr radii ρ", -20 Degree],
   Rotate["transferred momentum\n q in atomic unit", 60 Degree],
   Rotate["form factor\n\n", 95 Degree]};
```

[`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) the argument to [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html)

```
plt = Plot3D[
   Evaluate@f7[4, 2, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, a, q],
   {a, 1, 5}, {q, 0, .6},
   PlotRange -> Full,
   Background -> White,
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},
   ColorFunction -> Function[{a, q, z}, White],
   PlotRange -> Full,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   LabelStyle -> Black,
   BoxStyle -> Black,
   TicksStyle -> Black,
   AxesStyle -> Black];
```

**EDIT:** For earlier versions with which [`AbsoluteOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html) does not provide explicit ticks, use the output of

```
ticks = AbsoluteOptions[plt, Ticks][[1, -1]]

(* {{{1., "1", {0.00329516, 0.}}, {1.2, "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {1.4, 
   "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {1.6, "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {1.8, 
   "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {2., "2", {0.00329516, 0.}}, {2.2, 
   "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {2.4, "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {2.6, 
   "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {2.8, "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {3., 
   "3", {0.00329516, 0.}}, {3.2, "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {3.4, 
   "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {3.6, "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {3.8, 
   "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {4., "4", {0.00329516, 0.}}, {4.2, 
   "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {4.4, "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {4.6, 
   "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {4.8, "", {0.0019771, 0.}}, {5., 
   "5", {0.00329516, 0.}}}, {{0., "0.0", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.02, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.04, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.06, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.08, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.1, 
   "0.1", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.12, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.14, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.16, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.18, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.2, "0.2", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.22, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.24, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.26, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.28, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.3, 
   "0.3", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.32, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.34, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.36, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.38, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.4, "0.4", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.42, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.44, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.46, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.48, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.5, 
   "0.5", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.52, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.54, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.56, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.58, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.6, "0.6", {0.0040624, 0.}}}, {{-0.22, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.21, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.2, 
   "-0.20", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {-0.19, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.18, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.17, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.16, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.15, "-0.15", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {-0.14, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.13, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.12, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.11, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.1, 
   "-0.10", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {-0.09, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.08, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.07, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.06, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.05, "-0.05", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {-0.04, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.03, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.02, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {-0.01, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0., 
   "0.00", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.01, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.02, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.03, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.04, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.05, "0.05", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.06, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.07, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.08, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.09, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.1, 
   "0.10", {0.0040624, 0.}}, {0.11, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.12, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.13, "", {0.00243744, 0.}}, {0.14, 
   "", {0.00243744, 0.}}}}
```

Then,

```
ticks = ticks /.
   {{3.2, "", r___} :> {3.2, lbls[[1]], r}, 
    {0.28, "", r___} :> {0.28, lbls[[2]], r}, 
    {-0.06, "", r___} :> {-0.06, lbls[[3]], r}}; *)

Show[plt, Ticks -> ticks]
```

[image]

Comment: I copied your code and run it but the axes labels are disappeared now. In your fugure, it is showing as I want. I am not sure what I am missing. Is it related to version of Mathematica? I am using 12.2.0. @Bob Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: I used v13.1; prior to v13.0, it appears that `AbsoluteOptions[plt, Ticks]` evaluates to `{Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}}` rather than including the actual ticks. You would need to specify all of the ticks in order to include the ticks used for axes labels.

Comment: I could able to run the code in v13.1, and it is working. Thank you so much for your help. @Bob